# Stuck with Thread and updateGraphics

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, swing, graphics

Im trying to make a sortingalgorithm by drawlines, so it looks like a diagram. The problem here is that I can't see the progress as a moving diagram, when the array is sorting. When I type in the time for sleep, the outprint just shows me long lines, and after the sleeplines it shows the complete sorted diagram. So I just need to do something see the progress while the diagram is sorting. In this case I'm using bublesort. Im taking every help as a big thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public class newClass extends JFrame {

public newClass() {
    final Thread hei = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            bublesort();
        }
    });
    hei.start();
}
int[] array = { 400, 420, 380, 120, 340, 179, 454, 400, 420, 380, 120, 340, 179, 454, 400, 420, 380, 120, 340, 179 };

public void updateGraphic() {
    paint(this.getGraphics());
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int tjue = 20;
        g.drawLine(i * tjue, 500, i * tjue, array[i]);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length - 1; x++) {
            if (array[x] > array[x + 1]) {
                int temp = array[x];
                array[x] = array[x + 1];
                array[x + 1] = temp;
                updateGraphic();
                this.validate();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(newClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where is bublesort method?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it's a good idea not to use Thread.sleep or do performance-intensive stuff in a paint method. This is because the paint method executes on the event dispatch thread, which Swing relies on to perform GUI updates. Instead, run your sort in a separate thread, and call `repaint()` instead of `updateGraphic()` in that thread. It looks like you already have a `bubbleSort()` method, so just adapt it like so:

```
for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length - 1; x++) {
        if (array[x] > array[x + 1]) {
            int temp = array[x];
            array[x] = array[x + 1];
            array[x + 1] = temp;
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(newClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll want to remove this code from your paint method.

Comment: Instead of catching and pretty much ignoring the Interrupt, you should exit the loop.  That way in the future you could stop this process.

Answer (score 1):

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel (or JComponent) and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a working example.

If you want to animate the painting then you should use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation. Search the table of contents from the tutorial to find a section on `How to Use Swing Timers` for more information.